# Regex in PHP - How do I capture the last instance of a character?

Tags: php, regex

My code.

```
$string = "(ILLUSTRATION 1D) - AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit";
$string = preg_replace("/(\(ILLUSTRATION.*\))(.*-|\s)(.*)/", "$3", $string);
```

I'm getting `"Piece Inspection Toolkit"` for `$string` because the second capturing group is `" - AWS 10-"` instead of `" -"`.

How do I get the 2nd capturing group to be `" -"`?

Comment: Your regex [does not match the string at all](https://regex101.com/r/eocwyd/1). Please share the *exact* code that does not work.

Comment: `(` and `)` are special characters in regex so they need to be escaped to be literal. You also need to quantify the `.` for it to extend to more than 1 character.

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted the wrong code. I fixed it.

Comment: @DeeBoy Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/EpVQQw/1 ? You are using too many capture groups if you are only using `$3` in the replacement.  It would improve your post if you included your expected output.  ... and perhaps 2 more input strings with their expected output.  This helps readers to understand your intent and the variability of your input text.  As far as I can see, you don't need regex for this task.  This is why it is important to clarify the variability of your input.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks. I just realized why I am using the 2nd capturing group. Code is kinda old and I just looked at my tests. There are a bunch of input strings that are different. I will try and fix. Thanks again.

Comment: You may try `(\(ILLUSTRATION.*\))(.*\s-|\s)(.*)`

Comment: @DeeBoy ...gosh there must be a lot of variations!  I'll check back later to see if you've done the necessary question edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go ahead and run with some reasonable assumptions about your input strings and grant that regex is merited.

`preg_replace()` seems an unnecessary choice when you just want to return a match.  For this reason, `preg_match()` is better suited.

*I'll use `var_export()` to prove that it is a clean, space-trimmed output.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04bec8fbf62200a61375942bf069674a5645acbb))

```
$strings=[
    "(ILLUSTRATION 1D) - AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit",
    "(ILLUSTRATION 1-D) - AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit",
    "(ILLUSTRATION 1D)- AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit",
    "(ILLUSTRATION 1D) -AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit",
    "(ILLUSTRATION 1-D)-AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit"    
];
foreach($strings as $string){
    var_export(preg_match('/\)[ -]*\K.*/',$string,$match)?$match[0]:'no match');
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit'
'AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit'
'AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit'
'AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit'
'AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit'
```

Pattern Explanation:

- match the earliest `)`
- match zero or more of the following characters in any order/sequence: `space` & `hyphen`
- restart the fullstring match using `\K`
- match the remainder of the string with `.*`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the code and reformat it as follows:

```
<?php

$string = "(ILLUSTRATION 1D) - AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit";

$pattern = "/.+\s+-\s*(.+)/";

$string = preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $string);


print_r($string);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/55LCA)

The function [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) replaces the string with the "remembered" pattern match if the indicated pattern match occurs.

`$string` contains the target string.  The `$pattern` consists of one or more characters followed by one or more spaces, then a hyphen and optionally one or more spaces which is then followed by one or more characters.  The last one or more characters will be "remembered" in a match.  Since that is the only pattern to remember that is the value that `$1` contains.  So when the  pattern match occurs with the string, the contents of `$string` are replaced by the value of `$1`.

Or, you could use [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split), as follows:

```
<?php

$string = "(ILLUSTRATION 1D) - AWS 10-Piece Inspection Toolkit";
$pattern = "/\s+-\s*/";

$nustring = preg_split( $pattern, $string )[1];

print_r($nustring);
```

The advantage of preg_split() is that it concerns itself with substrings of $string.  Also the pattern to split on is simple, one or more spaces, followed by a hypen and then optionally one or more spaces, followed by one or more characters.

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/ES54S)